# Java - text to array to text

Tags: java, string, sorting, io, integer

I'm looking for the best way to read integers+strings from a small text file, save them in an array, add a few new integers+strings, sort them by integers and then write highest few in the same file. (sth like highscores)

#### Example:

*sth.txt*:

```
5 aa
4 bb
3 cc
3 dd
```

Into

```
a["5 aa","4 bb","3 cc","3 dd"]
```

Add some new strings

```
a["5 aa","4 bb","3 cc","3 dd","1 aa","7 bb"]
```

Sort and write back into *sth.txt*

```
7 bb
5 aa
4 bb
3 cc
```

How can I do it in Java?

Comment: Try a Java Map, which will allow you to associate a string to a score.

Comment: There are many questions about how to read text file in Java, how to store data in arrays (or list), how to sort arrays/lists, how to write text to file. Which step you are having problem with? Show us your code and describe specific problem which you are facing.

Comment: Use a class to parse the test file and use a List of that class then use Collections.sort with a custom comparator ! can you do that ?

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz Sorry, should've started with that. I tried to read/write to different files first, then found like 10 different ways to do it and got lost somewhere. My latest and, I think, most succesful try: http://pastebin.com/m424enLC

Answer (score 0):

**You can do as follow, code contains a comments to make a better understanding.**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Data[] map = new Data[6];
    //Then read the data from your file , in my case
    //i will make a dummy data.
    map[0] = new Data(5, "aa");
    map[1] = new Data(4, "bb");
    map[2] = new Data(3, "cc");
    map[3] = new Data(3, "dd");
    map[4] = new Data(1, "aa");
    map[5] = new Data(7, "bb");
    //Then sorting this array
    java.util.Arrays.sort(map);
    //Then print the highet 4 records
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println(map[i].FirstPart + " " + map[i].SecondPart);
    }
}
```

Making a class than fits to your need assuming that the first part of the record is of type `int` and the second part is a `String`

```
class Data implements Comparable<Data> {

    int FirstPart;
    String SecondPart;

    public Data(int FirstPart, String SecondPart) {
        this.FirstPart = FirstPart;
        this.SecondPart = SecondPart;
    }
//compareTo method will be called whenever you call a sort method like
// "java.util.Arrays.sort(map);" in the main method

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Data o) {
        if (this.FirstPart < o.FirstPart) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
7 bb
5 aa
4 bb
3 dd
```

Comment: What if two objects have equal `FirstPart`? Should we swap such elements? Anyway you don't need to write conditions manually. Let `Integer.compare` do it for you and simply return its result.

Comment: If two objects have equal `FirstPart`, then he can do `first occur >> first show` or vice versa. Or even he can then sort depending on the `SecondPart`. Its all about the OP needed @Pshemo

Comment: Yeah, seems like it's good as well, I'll try to fix the errors and answer. @Pshemo I didn't precise, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: My concern is that shown comparison doesn't respect ordering rules. Normally if `A>B` it means that `B<A`. So it is expected that `sgn(A.compareTo(B)) = -sgn(B.compareTo(A))`. But this fails in your case if A and B will be considered equal (like `map[2]` and `map[3]`), since you will always get -1 regardless if you are comparing (A,B) or (B,A). This may cause `IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!`. For now algorithms can allow this mistake, but it doesn't mean it will always be like that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample solution including reading and writing to file:

```
public class Main {
    static class Entry<T, U> {
        public T value1;
        public U value2;

        public Entry(T value1, U value2) {
            this.value1 = value1;
            this.value2 = value2;
        }
    }

    static Entry<Integer, String> parseLine(String line) {
        String[] intAndString = line.split(" ");
        Integer i = Integer.parseInt(intAndString[0]);
        String s = intAndString[1];
        return new Entry<>(i, s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get("spl.txt");
        List<Entry<Integer, String>> resultList = new LinkedList<>();
        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
            String nextLine;
            while ((nextLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (nextLine.equals("\n") || nextLine.isEmpty()) continue;
                resultList.add(parseLine(nextLine));
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(resultList, (e1, e2) -> e1.value1 - e2.value1 != 0 ? e1.value1 - e2.value1 : e1.value2.compareTo(e2.value2));
        try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path)) {
            resultList.forEach((e) -> {
                try {
                    writer.write(e.value1 + " " + e.value2 + "\n");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Encapsulation of class Entry omitted due to readability.
 
Sorting in **ascending** order.
Hope it will help.

Comment: Yeah, that's nearly exactly what i was looking for. The problem is, they were written in one line without visible separators (like "\n" didn't work), so I separated them with [enter] and saved and reran the app and I got a nasty exception: http://pastebin.com/5TT6HqxC. I can't see why, since they were separated with [enter] originally.

Comment: The problem was in the new line sign at the end of the file, please check my new solution.

Comment: Somehow it still works the same for me - returns the strings in one line and ends with a new line, like the "\n" only worked at the end and also seems to add empty chars somewhere, because whenever I just put enters between them and delete the new line sign at the end (checked - it doesn't matter if I delete it or not), I get the exception I mentioned above.

Comment: Ok I changed it. but keep in mind, that it works for the format which you gave in question: number string and new line after, for example: "5 aa"

Comment: Yup, file's always read well, but the result is always like C's strcpy of all lines, like "1 aa2 aa3 aa" + new line at the end. After I separate the lines with [enter], delete new line at the end, save the file, close it and rerun, it always throws that exception. After I delete whole text form the text file and retype manually, it doesn't throw the exception, but the result is the same. Checked that one as well, still the same. I don't know why, though, as far as I understand Java, your code seems legit for me.

Comment: Yes, pure copypaste, just changed the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Check Below Solution --

```
abc.txt
4 test1
6 test2
0 test3
12 test4
5 test5
9 test6
```

---

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;


public class ReadWriteDataInFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String path="C:\\test\\";
        String fileName=path+"abc.txt";
        String newFileName=path+"abcNew.txt";

        System.out.println("Reading Data from File "+fileName + " started...");
        Map<Integer, String> readDataFromTextFile = readDataFromTextFile(fileName);

        System.out.println("Writing Sorted Data to File "+newFileName + " started...");
        writeDataInNewFile(readDataFromTextFile,newFileName);
        System.out.println("Writing Data to File Completed...");
    }


    private static void writeDataInNewFile(Map<Integer, String> readDataFromTextFile, String newFileName) throws IOException {

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(newFileName, "UTF-8");

        Iterator it = readDataFromTextFile.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            String data1=pair.getKey() + " " + pair.getValue();
            writer.println(data1);
        }
        writer.close();
    }

    private static Map<Integer, String> readDataFromTextFile(String fileName) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(input);

        String data;
        String result[] ;

        Map<Integer,String> dataMap= new TreeMap<Integer,String> ();
        while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
            result = data.split(" ");
            dataMap.put(Integer.parseInt(result[0]), result[1]);
        }
        return dataMap;
    }
}
```

---

```
newabc.txt
0 test3
4 test1
5 test5
6 test2
9 test6
12 test4
```

---

Comment: This one works for me. I'll try to add some new strings between reading and writing then copy "newabc.txt" into "abc.txt" and tell how it worked.

Comment: sure , post your results as well.